# FFT in C++ AMP Throw CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN error

Tags: directx, c++-amp

I am trying to use C++ AMP in Visual C++ 2017 on Windows 10 (updated to the latest) and I find the archived FFT library from C++ AMP team on codeplex. I try to run the sample code, however the program throws ran out of memory error when creating DirectX FFT. I solve that problem by following the [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/686fa16b-d264-4538-9854-33432004477d/amp-fft-library-does-not-work-with-amdintel-gpus-on-windows-81?forum=parallelcppnative) on Microsoft forum.

However, the problem doesn't stop. When the FFT library tries to create Unordered Access View, it throws error of CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN. I did not try to operate on clipboard anyhow.

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I solve the problem. The original post mentioned that we need to create a new DirectX device and then create accelerator view upon it. Then I pass that view to ctor of fft as the second parameter.

`fft(
        concurrency::extent<_Dim> _Transform_extent, 
        const concurrency::accelerator_view& _Av = concurrency::accelerator().default_view, 
        float _Forward_scale = 0.0f, 
        float _Inverse_scale = 0.0f)`

However, I still have crashes of the CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN.

After reading the code, I realize that I need to create array on that DirectX views too. So I started to change:

`array<std::complex<float>,dims> transformed_array(extend, directx_acc_view);`

The idea comes from the different behaviors of `create_uav()`. The internal buffers and the precomputing caused no problem, but the samples' calls trigger the clipboard error. I guess the device matters here, so I do that change.

I hope my understanding is correct and anyway there is no such errors now.